# Visual Studio JavaScript Intelliense for VB generated controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

We have a user control system in place that allows us to create user controls which generate the HTML and JS necessary for the user control to function. The initial values or options are set in VB/C# and the control is rendered like this:

```
@Code
  Dim ms As New ControlModels.MultiSelectModel("ms")
  UserControlHelpers.RenderMultiSelect(ms)
End Code
```

At this point a JS user control is created, set to the variable "ms". This is what is would create in JS:

```
var ms = new userControls.MultiSelect("ms");
```

We can access the user control's values via this variable within JS and it works really well for us.

The problem is that VS's intellisense cannot pick up on what type of object it is and cannot provide any information into the newly created object. If we created the object on the page directly without using VB to create and render the control, intellisense is able to know what type of object it is and give us methods and properties of that object.

What can we do to allow us the correct intelliense? I know that we can add our own listeners to VS but I can't see a way for it to gain access to any useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to treat loosely-typed ***JavaScript*** as you would strongly-typed and compiled ***VB*** and ***C#***.

This is more than an *Intelli-sense* problem. It's the challenge of having a tool anticipate dynamic types.

```
var ms = new userControls.MultiSelect("ms");
```

You create types in ***ASP.NET***, then serialize them to ***JSON*** and render the client-side instructions. But if you are using *Intelli-sense*, then ***ASP.NET*** code has not run yet, and ***JavaScript***, being a dynamic language, will calmly wait and evaluate what you return to your generic `var`.

You are effectively fishing `upstream` of your prey.

---

**You do still have options:**

In order to get the benefits of *Intelli-sense*, you would have to prototype `userControls.MultiSelect()` in advance.

refer to **[understanding-prototypes-in-javascript](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)**

Also, take a look at this ***VS2012*** **[JavaScript Intellisense](https://github.com/dotnetwise/VS2012-Javascript-Intellisense)** tool: